# Crypto++ SHA1 Function

Tags: visual-c++, crypto++

I can't figure out what's wrong with my function - it causes a breakpoint on return.

```
std::string generateHash(std::string source)
{
    CryptoPP::SHA1 hash;
    byte digest[CryptoPP::SHA1::DIGESTSIZE];
    hash.CalculateDigest(digest, (const byte*)source.c_str(), source.size());
    std::string output;
    CryptoPP::HexEncoder encoder;
    CryptoPP::StringSink test = CryptoPP::StringSink(output);
    encoder.Attach((CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation*)&CryptoPP::StringSink(output));
    encoder.Put(digest, sizeof(digest));
    encoder.MessageEnd();
    return output; // here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`encoder.Attach((CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation*)&CryptoPP::StringSink(output));`

In this line, `CryptoPP::StringSink(output)` is a temporary object. After this call `CryptoPP::StringSink(output)` no longer exists. So If you try to follow its address (`encoder.Attach` and `encoder.Put`), you will get undefined behavior. (Like you should never return the address of a local variable)

My code for reference:

```
 std::string generateHash(std::string source)
  {
      CryptoPP::SHA1 hash;
      byte digest[CryptoPP::SHA1::DIGESTSIZE];
      hash.CalculateDigest(digest, (const byte*)source.c_str(), source.size());
      std::string output;
      CryptoPP::HexEncoder encoder;
      CryptoPP::StringSink test = CryptoPP::StringSink(output);
      encoder.Attach(new CryptoPP::StringSink(output));
      encoder.Put(digest, sizeof(digest));
      encoder.MessageEnd();
      return output;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>    CryptoPP::HexEncoder encoder;
>    CryptoPP::StringSink test = CryptoPP::StringSink(output);
>    encoder.Attach((CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation*)&CryptoPP::StringSink(output));
> ```

Onemouth's solution is correct, but here's why you are having trouble:

- The `StringSink(output)` is a temporary on the stack, and it will be cleaned up when the `StringSink` destructors run
- `HexEncoder` 'owns' the pointer to `StringSink(output)`, so the `HexEncoder` will call delete on `StringSink(output)`

So the `StringSink` is cleaned up twice.

For completeness, the `StringSink` does *not* delete the string `output` because it takes a reference, not a pointer.

This is documented behavior in the [README.txt](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cryptopp/browser/trunk/c5/Readme.txt):

```
88  *** Important Usage Notes ***
89  
90  1. If a constructor for A takes a pointer to an object B (except primitive
91  types such as int and char), then A owns B and will delete B at A's
92  destruction.  If a constructor for A takes a reference to an object B,
93  then the caller retains ownership of B and should not destroy it until
94  A no longer needs it.
```

Though it would be *highly* unusual, you *might* be able to do what you are trying to do and fix it as follows (but I would *not* recommend doing it the way you are):

```
encoder.Attach(new Redirector(&CryptoPP::StringSink(output)));
```

The `Redirector` stops the ownership chain. When the `Redirector` is destroyed, it does *not* destroy its attached transformation (which is the `StringSink`). But again, its not the way to use the library.

`Redirector`s are useful in other places in the library, but not really in this case.